# Kotlin reflection returns incorrect type

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have an activity that implements a listener with a generic type that requires me to implement the onResponse function.

The listener is defined in the following format:

```
public interface ListenerClass<T> {
    onResponse(T type)
}
```

And my activity implements it using `T == ModelClass`.

```
class MyActivity : ListenerClass<ModelClass> {

    (...)

    override fun onResponse(response: ModelClass) {
         (...)
    }
}
```

The listener is part of an SDK so I cannot change any code in there. They use a piece of reflection to get the type of my 'ModelClass' using the following code:

```
listener.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[onResponseIndex].getParameterTypes()[0]
```

The result of this code should be `Class<ModelClass>` but I get `Class<Object>`. I found out that when I call the code above on a Java class, I get the correct result, but my activity is written in Kotlin.

1) How can I get the parameter type of a kotlin function using reflection?

2) If I have an answer to question 1 I still won't be able to change the SDK's code. Is there anything I can write in my Kotlin code that makes the piece of code above find the correct parameter class type?

Comment: How are you calling that code?

Comment: The SDK has a reference to my Activity which is 'listener'

Comment: Try annotating the MyActivity class with @JvmSuppressWildcards. If I correctly understand what the problem is, this should help. http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics

Comment: @JvmSuppressWildcards does not work unfortunately. The result of the reflection as written above is still the same -> It returns 'Object' instead of 'ModelClass'. I updated the post with some information about the Listener.